# Ошибка git push на собственный сервер

Tags: git, push

Пытаюсь выгрузить на собственный Linux сервер через Pycharm, но выдает ошибку, я так понимаю проблема с разрешениями, но где и как это исправить не могу понять.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@***.***.**.***:/home/swapnil/project-1.git'
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [remote rejected] (unpacker error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было прописать команду в текущем директории сервера

```
sudo chown -R git:git .
```

Comment: очень плохой совет. раз вы держите репозиторий в домашнем каталоге пользователя (вероятно, `swapnil`), то и подключаться вам надо было как этому пользователю, а не пользователю `git`. рекомендую вернуть принадлежность файлов/каталогов назад, и изменить url.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin можно по подробней), я новичок только пытаюсь разобраться как это работает

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL : `пользователь@хост`. в качестве имени пользователя вы указываете `git`. что в вашем случае неверно.